# Copying data to Ubuntu from MacOS 10.15

Tags: macosx

Just back to Linux after a long holiday. Running MacOS 10.15 on a MacBookPro with Ubuntu running nicely from a USB stick. I'd like to bring over some data from the MacBook to Ubuntu - namely, Safari favorites, address book and calendar to start with. Would be nice to have total access to ALL data if possible.
Thanks

Comment: Please make this into four questions to comply with the house rules regarding questions having a reasonable scope https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask . Your question #1 is answered below, so click [edit] and edit your question regarding exporting remaining data into other questions.  Also, please specify which Ubuntu app you want to receive the Address Book data. Also, please specify which Ubuntu app you want to receive the Calendar data.

Comment: Ubuntu's about choice, and you have a broad selection of apps to receive your Address Book and your Calendar. You can review apps which could receive your Address Book at http://alternativeto.net/software/mozilla-thunderbird/?platform=linux and apps to receive your Calendar data at http://alternativeto.net/browse/search/?q=calendar&platform=linux

Answer (score 0):

[Safari favorites export to Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1001372):
In Safari, open the File menu and choose Export Bookmarks. Save bookmarks.html somewhere handy.
In Firefox, open the Bookmarks menu and choose Show All Bookmarks.
In the Library window, click the Import and Backup button and choose Import Bookmarks from HTML. Pick the bookmarks.html file you exported earlier.